# make a table with jstl and ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jstl

I'm writing a jsp where in the data has to be pulled from database and display it in different rows. Currently, I'm able to pull the data but unable to know how can i display them in rows. Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var request;
    function sendInfo() {
        var v = document.vinform.t1.value;
        var url = "Controller?val=" + v;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        try {
            request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.send();
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }
    }

    function getInfo() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var val = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById('amit').innerHTML = val;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <marquee>
        <h1>This is an example of ajax</h1>
    </marquee>
    <form name="vinform">
        Enter id:<input type="text" name="t1" onkeyup="sendInfo()">
    </form>

    <span id="amit"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

**DataDAO**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataDao {
    private Connection connection;

    public DataDao() throws Exception {
        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFrameWork(String frameWork) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String data;
        try {

            ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from statusTable where [case owner]=?");
            ps.setString(1, frameWork);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                data = rs.getString("case Number");
                list.add(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.dao.DataDao;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try {
            String id = request.getParameter("val");

            DataDao dataDao = new DataDao();
            ArrayList<String> list = dataDao.getFrameWork(id);

            String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.getWriter().write(searchList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**DBUTILITY**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBUtility {
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (connection != null)
            return connection;
        else {
            // Store the database URL in a string
            String userName = "sa";
            String password = "T!ger123";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver:XXXXXX;DatabaseName=TEST";

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            // set the url, username and password for the databse
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this program the output is as in below format.

```
["2086351 ","2086356 ","2086357 ","2086358 ","2086358 "]
```

But i want the data to be displayed in a table with the values in different rows(values are separated by a line in the screenshot).

I know that we can get this done by using.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="rowObj" items="${myClass.myArrayList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${rowObj.column1}</td>
            <td>${rowObj.column2}</td>
            <td>${rowObj.column3}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

But i'm unable to know where is this supposed to be called. Please let me know how can i fix this.

Here the problem is not about getting the data, it is how it is displayed.

Thanks

Comment: dynamically crate table on successful response

Comment: Hi @rupesh_padhye, That's what i'm unable to do. I dunno how can i make this.

Comment: The JSP file looks about right to me, but it would be easier to see the columns if there were some space between them. At the moment, it looks like a big String. My suggestion to you is to check what is being returned by the controller. How many entities are being returned by dataDao.getFrameWork(id)?

Comment: Hi @KarlDahlgren, currently there are 5 entities returned, mentioned with a red line in the screenshot